# setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int) not working

Tags: android, xml, graphics, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have a few `EditText views` where I want to set the image on the left and `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` does not seems to be working. The graphics do not seem to be getting changed.

does anyone know why this might be the case?

Here is how I am setting the drawables:

```
        mFirstname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.user_icon, 0, 0, 0);
        mLastname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.user_icon, 0, 0, 0);
        mEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mailicon, 0, 0, 0);
        mPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.lockicon, 0, 0, 0);
        mDateOfBirth.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.calico, 0, 0, 0);
        mCity.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mailicon, 0, 0, 0);
        mStreet.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mailicon, 0, 0, 0);
        mPostcode.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mailicon, 0, 0, 0);
        mPhoneNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mailicon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a radio button. The call simply has no effect, the image always appears to the right of the button. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes! I did. Sorry for replying a week late. So It seems to effect devices with ICS on it. solution posted below

Comment: what do you mean below?? the solution which was posted by @user Denis Glakiy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If anyone else has this seemingly unexplainable issue then try the following:

- Go to your XML template.
- Remove the XML image representing it.
- Your view should refresh the compounddrawable.

basically this portion of the view does not seem to get reinflated on ICS devices. Hopefully this solves the problem for some people!

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to setup compound drawable on the next (after layout) cycle of the UI loop:

```
final TextView viewById = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

viewById.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        viewById.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, 0, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mBtnNext=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

Drawable drawableRight=new IconicsDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
               .icon(Ionicons.Icon.ion_arrow_right_a)
                .color(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack))
                .sizeDp(24);

mBtnNext.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,drawableRight,null);
```

Try this your problem will get resolved.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you explain what you have done there

Answer (score 0):

The problem arise when you have defined Drawable (top, left, right, bottom) Image in xml layout. It's like the xml drawable is applied after the one defined in code. Remove the xml one and do it in code where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used Ionicons plugins. Go to the following links. You will get some idea about how to use IonIcons in your android project.

[IonIcons For Android](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics)

After implement the above Ionicons plugins in your project. You will get IconicsDrawable class.

[Gradle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRuC0.png)

[See here to know how to drive IconicsDrawable class in your class](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics#use-as-drawable)

```
mBtnNext=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

Drawable drawableRight=new IconicsDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
               .icon(Ionicons.Icon.ion_arrow_right_a)
                .color(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack))
                .sizeDp(24);

mBtnNext.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,drawableRight,null);
```

I hope you will understand now.